# What is the different between getColor() and getColorStateList() in Android

Tags: android, colors, android-resources

I'm using `getColor()` method to select color from resources. But I found that there is another method called `getColorStateList()`. Which one is easy to use and what is the difference between them?

Comment: I suggest you to look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList(int) return type and how to use ? As name suggest and answered  ColorStateList maps the state with color and when you applied it to View then color changes according to current state of View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets assume that you want to **setBackgroundColor** to a view for example a **linearLayout**.
if you want its **background color to be permanent** ,you would want to use **getColor()** to set a **certain color**.
but if you want its color **to change on different states and events** like **pressed state** or **not pressed state** you would want to set resource id of the **xml** file containing the code for these color change tasks.

here is what im saying in code:

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
```

line of code above sets the permanent color of linearLayout to red.

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.layout_background));
```

and this single line of code above will set the background color to red when layout is pressed and white when its not pressed.

layout_background.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:color="@color/red" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
       android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Comment: `getColor` is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

**getColor()**
Returns a color integer associated with a particular resource ID

**getColorStateList()**
ColorStateLists are created from XML resource files defined in the "color" subdirectory directory of an application's resource directory. The XML file contains a single "selector" element with a number of "item" elements inside. For example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="@color/sample_focused" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:state_enabled="false"
           android:color="@color/sample_disabled_pressed" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false"
           android:color="@color/sample_disabled_not_pressed" />
   <item android:color="@color/sample_default" />
 </selector>
```